# Why does all data go away when restarting Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, data-loss

I don't understand this paradigm I guess?
For a small single server or development environment... I hate having to load 100's of thousands of records just to analyze it in a graph... am I missing the big picture here?

**UPDATE (3/21/2012 10:38a):**
**My current setup:**

- Default Install
- Default Configs
- Server Setup
- Creating nodes via REST API

Comment: We need to know more to help you. Is this the server or an embedded database? Neo4j should definitely not drop data between restarts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you instantiate your database, embedded or server? Are you running ImpermanentGraphDatabase, because that's the in-memory test database. If you use the normal EmbeddedGraphDatabase your graph is persisted trasactionally along the way when you insert your data.

Please give a little more information.

Comment: If you could update your answer with some brief quick steps or links to get my server config setup so that it doesn't lose data, I'll go ahead and mark this accepted... Thanks so much for your time! I read through this link: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-embedded.html but I still don't understand where I'm suppose to set a property or fix a config file...?

Answer (score 0):

If using Java embedded transactions must be closed when saving objects or they might get lost. In earlier versions this was done by calling `finally { tx.finish(); }`, later versions (2.1+) it should happen automatically when instantiated within the *try-with-resource*. (This makes it possible to run into problems if the `Transaction tx` is instantiated outside the try clause).

```java
GraphDatabaseService graphDb =  new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
  // create some nodes here
}
```